# HTML banner in header doesn't show

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a image as the background in my header, but nothing seems to happen.

This my css code where I set the specs of my image(500 * 2000):

```
header{
background-image: url(../images/banner2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0 auto;
max-height:100px;
width: 100%;
}
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body id = "contact">
    <header></header>
    <div id="page">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1><a href="../html/index.html" id="logoLink">Baby kleding online</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../html/index.html"id="homenav">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../html/kleding.html"id="kledingnav">Kleding</a></li>
            <li><a class="inuse" href="../html/contact.html"id="contactnav">Contact</a>      </li>
            <li><a href="../html/vragen.html"id="vragennav">Vragen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Images">
        <b target="_blank" href="kleding.htm">
            <img src="../images/logo.PNG" alt="Boy1" width="300" height="140">
        </b>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your header doesn't have a height set ;-)

Comment: Either you need to have height and width set or you need to fill something inside of the '<header></header>'

Comment: Also, unless the `header` is positioned in some way, you don't need `width: 100%;`

Comment: height: 250px;
set height in your header css..

Comment: I set the heigt to 100% still no results :(

Comment: Note: When you set the header to `max-height: 100px;`, only the top 100px of your image (with a height of 500px when I read it correctly) will be shown. It won't be resized when you use it as a background-image!

Comment: That will only work if the parent has a height, you need to set the height value in `px`

Comment: @ Thomas Pen : set like this height: 250px; it will work

Comment: Set the height as the height of the picture or the height you want to use on the header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix your problem you have to assign a height to your header. 
This can be done by using the `height: [Amount of pixels]px;`

Or you can add something in between the `<header></header>` tags that will make the header show.

Comment: I set the height to 100% still no results

Comment: Edited.... set the height to the amount of pixels you want.... If you set it to more than your image it will just leave it blank where the image is to small to reach..

Comment: @ Thomas Pen: Welcome...:-)